# Generating a range in MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql

I read through other similar questions before, but none seems to have answered my question. Apologies if this is a repeat of something else, but I couldn't seem to find this question answered elsewhere.

I've got a database table that looks more or less like this:

`ID | URL | Title | Episode | Sequence | Created_at | Modified_at`

These are used to assign specific links to episodes of podcasts, and they're displayed in the order illustrated by the `Sequence`. I've built a Laravel framework that interacts with the table, and I'm able to change the order of things by manipulating the sequence, but I'm having trouble removing things and maintaining the sequence for the purposes that I want it. Say I have the following four things in the table:

```
id = 5, sequence = 1
id = 6, sequence = 3
id = 7, sequence = 2
id = 8, sequence = 4
```

When viewing the site, the page would list them in `id` order 5, 7, 6, 8. However, if I realize that there's been a problem with one of the links, I would remove it, at which point I might be left with `id`s 5, 7, 8. The sequence would be 1, 2, 4.

What I'm looking for at the moment is a way of "reseeding" the sequence column on a per-episode basis. It'd be something that basically takes all rows with a specific `episode`, sorts them in ascending order on `sequence`, and then "renumbers" them in ascending order. The sequence = 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 would change to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Why is that a problem since the number are always growing?

Comment: The problem comes when I need to change the order of things. If the sequence list is 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 and I want to move 5 "up" in the sequence, it needs to do a lot of extra work to realize there isn't a 4, etc. It would be far easier, from a development standpoint, if I could just swap the sequence values of the one before or after it, depending if I'm moving something up or down.

Comment: Can you show a little more of the data and just the ID and sequence... You can probably do a query getting proper sequence and numeric row representation without hard-code referencing the sequence.  You mention episodes, is there another element such as "My XYZ Show", Episodes 1-9 and they are all added in different orders hence the sequencing?

Comment: Right, every episode is part of a series and has an episode number, so the episode field might be mo124, g320, mmo114 etc.

Comment: So what I'm doing is "For episode 50 of Movieing On, show me all entries where episode = mo50, order it by sequence".

Answer (score 0):

It should be a relatively simple query such as

```
select
      YT.*
   from
      YourTable YT
   where
      YT.Episode = 'MO50'
   order by
      YT.Sequence
```

Now, if your sequences are creating gaps for whatever reason you could always implement a mySql variable to increment regardless of the ACTUAL sequence..  Try..

```
select
      @tmpRow := @tmpRow +1 as NewSequence,
      YT.*
   from
      YourTable YT,
      ( select @tmpRow := 0 ) sqlvars
   where
      YT.Episode = 'MO50'
   order by
      YT.Sequence
```

So, even if your actual sequences for a given show "MO50" are 2, 3, 8, 12, 15.  The actual column "NewSequence" would show as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Now, that said, you would STILL have the original "ID" column as the basis of editing any details and or remove episodes as needed...  Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a built-in feature that does what you need elegantly.

Here is a dumb way of doing it.

Suppose you want to move id=8 from sequence 4 to 2.

```
UPDATE episodes 
SET sequence = sequence+1 
WHERE episode='Episode Name' 
  AND sequence BETWEEN 2 AND 4;

UPDATE episodes
SET sequence = 2
WHERE id = 8;
```

You want to put this in a transaction always to ensure your sequence does not get out of kilter.

The `sequence+1` is for moving an item UP the list. If you are moving down it would be `-1`.

This also means you must maintain the sequence if you delete a row. So if you delete something you have to shift everything underneath it up one. Do that in a transaction too.

Where you might have a problem with this is if you have a unique key spanning the episode and sequence columns. Which you ought to strictly. You would have to assign a temporary sequence value on the row you are shifting first to avoid a duplicate key error.

Comment: Right, my problem comes in exactly that one sentence you breeze by: "So if you delete something you have to shift everything underneath it up one. Do that in a transaction too". The rest I'm having no problem with - not sure if I explained my problem properly. Creating, selecting, modifying, no problem. But if I remove a row, renumbering the rest of the rows is what I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Suppose you want to delete id=7 (sequence 2) from your table. You simply delete the row. Then -1 the sequence value for all rows `WHERE sequence > 2`. Do this in a transaction.